# Dual-Boot Kali Linux Wired Connection Not Working

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, router, kali-linux

When I plug in a Category 5 cable to get an Ethernet connection, the system detects a wired connection. However, I cannot access the Internet.

When I choose to connect to the wired connection, the display that shows the WiFi connection is just a loading bar. I have been trying to figure this out for days.

Here is some information:

```
root@kali:~# iwconfig
wlan0     IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"CenturyLink9642"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.462 GHz  Access Point: E8:37:7A:C8:2F:27   
          Bit Rate=72.2 Mb/s   Tx-Power=10 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=70/70  Signal level=-23 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:476   Missed beacon:0

wlan0mon  IEEE 802.11  Mode:Monitor  Tx-Power=0 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on

eth0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.
```

---

```
root@kali:~# iwconfig eth0
eth0      no wireless extensions.
```

---

```
root@kali:~# sudo ethtool -i eth0
driver: r8169
version: 
firmware-version: rtl8168g-2_0.0.1 02/06/13
expansion-rom-version: 
bus-info: 0000:08:00.0
supports-statistics: yes
supports-test: no
supports-eeprom-access: no
supports-register-dump: yes
supports-priv-flags: no
root@kali:~#
```

Answer (score 1):

**Iwconfig** is used for **wireless interfaces**.

Use **ifconfig** to configure your **wired** interfaces, or use the **network manager GUI** built-in.

You can use **lspci** to see if there were problems loading the Ethernet drivers.
Make sure what is listed is what you know the model of the card to be.

If you have further problems, Google & double check the compatible cards list for the Kali version you are using.